# Capturing F10 in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to capture the <kbd>F10</kbd> key in Delphi, but it seems to keep going to activating the menu because it gets converted from the vk_F10 to vk_menu or something.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to disable standard Windows UI behavior? Just because you don't use F10 to activate the menu doesn't mean your customers won't.

Comment: Very important comment by Rob Kennedy - you should never use any of the standard Windows keyboard shortcuts (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545461.aspx) for a different command than the default, and F10 is among them.

Comment: Unless, of course, it's not relevant. If you're writing a fullscreen app, for example, you most definitely do *not* want the user pulling up the Windows menu system.  (Then again, you probably won't have menus in that case, but you understand the general idea...)

Comment: F10 is the *application* menu, not the Windows menu. I agree with Rob; overriding this makes your app less accessible to people with disabilities.

Comment: I said the Windows *menu system*, not the "Windows Menu".

Answer (score 7):

The following OnKeyDown event added to my main form should work. Note you ned to set the key parameter to zero to prevent menu activation:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if key = VK_F10 then begin
     Label1.Caption := 'You hit F10';
     key := 0;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Indeed. But to keep F10 from activating the menu the Key parameter should also be set to 0.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't activate the menu for me as it stands.

Comment: it probably does activate the menu, but that will be lost by the showmessage changing focus. Try setting a label caption instead, and see if it does it then (with a menu present of course!)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, here's some code to make a keyboard hook using the Windows API: http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/install_a_keyboard_hook.html